# Jupyter notebook ipywidgets with buttons AND dropdowns in the SAME cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

In jupyter, I just want to display a dropdown with a list of consecutive integers AND also allow the associated integer variable to be incremented/decremented with inc and dec buttons (like a fwd/rev nav system). But no matter what I try it wont work. I either get no buttons or only buttons and no dropdowns.

I can use multiple drop downs using a select function and interactive statement:

widgets.interactive(select, time_sel = time_combo, LR_sel = LR_combo)

but I can't add buttons partly because I don't know how to add buttons via an interactive command.

```py
def select(time_sel = time_combo, LR_sel = LR_combo, FB_sel = FB_combo):
    . . . 

def bminus_onclick()
    . . .

def bplus_onclick()
    . . .

bminus = widgets.Button(
    description='<',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='',
    tooltip='NEXT hour')

bplus = widgets.Button(
    description='>',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='',
    tooltip='PREVIOUS hour')

time_combo = widgets.Dropdown(
    options = list(range(1,int(duration_inhours + 1))),
    value = 1,
    description='Time:', 
    disabled=False,)

LR_combo = widgets.Dropdown(
    options = ['BOTH','L','R'],
    value = 'BOTH',
    description = 'Side:',
    disabled = False,)

widgets.interactive(select, time_sel = time_combo, LR_sel = LR_combo)
```

I want to add the buttons, their event handlers and have the event handlers inc/dec the dropdown and/or the time_sel variable.